# How to disable star imports in Eclipse Juno

Tags: java, eclipse

How can I disable star imports in Eclipse Juno? I only want to import the classes that I use, and the IDE imports the entire package if I import a lot of classes that are in that package.

Comment: +1 I didn't realise Eclipse would ever do that. Better change my settings...

Comment: Did not know it either. I see that the default value in Eclipse is 99. It is a big number, therefore I recommend reading a bit about something called `Cohesion`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

*Preferences -> Java -> Code Style -> Organize Imports*, then change *Number of imports needed for .**.

If you change it to, say `2147483647`, you should be fine.

Answer (score 4):

I just have Indigo here, but I think it will help you:

Go to Preferences -> Java -> Code Style -> Organize imports.

There you will have the following fields:

```
Number of imports needed for .*
Number of static imports needed for .*
```

You can change it to match your needs. The default in Eclipse Indigo is 99, which is probably a good number to avoid the .* import.

Comment: Nothing is changed in Eclipse Mars (4.5).